# Maintenance page rules to be added at AWS load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I would like to redirect users to a custom maintenance page at a different domain. My setup includes AWS load balancer and EC2's.  If the EC2 behind the LB is not reachable, What rule I need to add at LB to check the status code and redirect to a maintenance page at different domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Route53 Failover with S3 is an option

I suggest that you can use **Route53** to achieve this with `failover` approach and maybe using a static website hosted on **Amazon S3** for cost optimization.

Here are the main ideas:

- Create the **Route 53 health check** which is your main site health check. If the status is failed, it redirects your traffic to the **failed-over endpoint**.
- Create a **record set for your primary endpoint** which points to your main site endpoint and (Your ALB DNS) with `Failover` routing policy.
- Create the **failover endpoint** which can be a static site (S3) or your maintenance page domain.

References:

- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/fail-over-s3-r53/

> Route53 Health-check with SNS & Lambda

You can use this feature as a standalone healh-check without affecting your domain setup as above. It will notify any status changes to a SNS topic and you can subscribe a **Lambda function** to help you updating your **Load Balancer listener** to redirect your traffic into another site.

[image: route53-health-check-setup]

Once setup properly, it creates an alarm for you to monitor your main site.

[image: route53-health-check-alarm]

With **Lambda function**, you can use **Boto3** (Python3) to update your Load Balancer based on 2 kind of events:

- `Unhealthy`: route traffic to another domain
- `Healthy`: route traffic to your target group

References:

- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-subscribe-sns-topic-same-account/
- https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.modify_listener

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already have a custom maintenance page that we use for many applications and have to use the same. I need to redirect to this page based on a status code received during the health checks. Can't use route 53 due to some limitations. This process should be automatic based on the status codes at health checks

Comment: @Learner Oh I see, let me update with another solution that I think you can try :D

Comment: Thanks again @Binh Nguyen. That means there is no simple way to add any rule in the listener for  a health check and redirect unless we use some custom code

Comment: @Learner I think so, if you use R53 so the story is simple :D But yes, most of cases, people do not use R53 then we have to customize here and there so it is up to you where you think the most efficient place to implement.

Comment: Thank you @Binh Nguyen for your inputs